# How to set initial property state on CSS Animation?

Tags: javascript, css, animation

I need to create a animation with the fallowing steps:

1. **Initial**: `elementA` with opacity 0;
2. **Once hover `elementA`'s container (let's call it `containerA`)**:

   - `elementA` translate from (-5px, 5px) to (0px, 0px);
   - `elementA` change opacity from `0` to `1`;
   - animation duration: 0.5s;
3. **Once mouse leave `containerA`**:

   - `elementA` change opacity from `1` to `0`;
   - `elementA` doesn't change translate position;
   - animation duration: 0.5s;

I've achieved this effect by adding/removing CSS class, you can see the here (https://jsbin.com/buqexadiru/edit?html,css,js,console,output)

My question is, how can I achieve this effect with pure CSS, without the *add/remove class* step; Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `transition` for the `opacity` and an `animation` for the `transform` when the container is hovered.

```css
.container {
  margin: 1em;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  background: lightblue;
  width: 50vh;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
}

.item {
  width: 20vh;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  background: green;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translate(0%, 0%);
  transition: opacity .5s;
}

.container:hover .item {
  opacity: 1;
  animation-name: appear;
  animation-duration: .5s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes appear {
  0% {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(0%, 0%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I was putting “opacity” in keyframes, is this why it wasn’t working? As I searched, the same property should be transitioned by same mechanism. Now with your example, it makes much more clear for me now! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Consider different transitions

```css
.container {
  margin: 1em;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  background: lightblue;
  width: 50vh;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
}

.item {
  width: 20vh;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  background: green;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transition: opacity .5s,transform 0s .5s; /* on mouset out, wait until opacity is done to change transform */
}

.container:hover .item {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translate(0%, 0%);
  transition: .5s; /* on hover transition both */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```